# Are there any tools to sandbox a malware application even more than the granted permissions on Android?

Tags: android, permissions, sandbox, privacy, malware

Suppose I want to run some program which requests too many permissions. For example, record from the microphone or read IMEI of my phone. However, there are no practical explanation why recording from the mic or IMEI number is needed for this particular application, except for data mining.

I want to try this app, but restrict its permissions. For example, if it reads IMEI, it should get random IMEI(but the same every time). If it tries to read the mic, it should get silence.

Some other interesting permissions:

1. Phonebook read/write access -
   returns zero contacts, pretend that
   write is OK, but actually do
   nothing.
2. Send SMS - pretend that SMS
   is sent, but do nothing.
3. Get list of
   visible Wi-Fi networks - return zero
   networks.

Obviously the tool should require a rooted phone. Are there any such tools?

Comment: You would probably need a custom rom to accomplish that. android.stackexchange.com might be a better place to inquire about custom roms.

Comment: Custom roms are built out of the components which are already available. But thanks for the pointer about android  specific stackexchange site. If there no such tool to sandbox the rogue app, I am going to start a project to create such a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [TISSA](http://www.techoncept.com/tissa-android-app-help-you-protect-your-information) prototype application, but it is not released, yet. In [CyanogenMod 7](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/22/cyanogenmod-adds-support-for-revoking-and-faking-app-permissions/) there is a setting to revoke application permissions, but if the app expects the API to return something useful instead of failing, it will crash, it is still not faking data.

Comment: I have found many aricles about TISSA published in 2011 but no article published in 2012. Is TISSA alive? Is it more than "it would be nice to to have"?

Answer (score 1):

You could download the Android SDK and use an emulator to test our the applications. You could then set info like your phone book and test out how the app is using that data.

Comment: Yes, SDK emulator is a viable option. But what if I want to actually _use_ that application?

Comment: Why would you want to use an application that is asking for more permissions than it should have? The only reasons I can think of for an app to do that are lazy coding or malicious intent. Neither promises a worthwhile user experience.

Answer (score 1):

i just found the free [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite&hl=en) for rooted phones. It pretends to protect sms, Internet access, contacts, Call Logs, Positioning, Phone ID, Phone Call and phone state.